# Making a sidenav

Tags: html, css

Heres my CSS code

```
.Month
{
    height: 20%;
    width: 275px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 50%;
    left: 71%;
    background-color: #FFB6C1;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I'm trying to make a navbar on the side, however I have run into a problem. The navbar pops up, however it follows the user around the website and I'm trying to make it not follow the user as they scroll throughout the website. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: where is the HTML ??

Comment: it follows because your `position` is `fixed` try changing it to `relative` or to `absolute` or remove it for `static` position.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it